# Calculating a limit or proving it does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I have the following function:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+3x+4})}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}}$$

The limit definition we are using is

to $-\infty$ such that $L = \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$ iff 
for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $M<0$ such that for every $x<M$ we have that $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert < \epsilon$.

I can see that the function is actually

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+3x+4})$$

I found that

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}}=1.$$

I can see that

$$(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+3x+4})$$

has no limit but I am unable to disprove it by the definition.

After I will be able to disprove it I guess by arithmetics of limit I will be able to prove that the entire function has no limit.

Any assistance will be welcomed.

Comment: It might be surprising, but $\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}$ does actually have a limit! Hint: multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}}$.

Comment: I tried and got to $\frac{-3(x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}}$ but did not understand how to move on from here

Comment: Going forward, with your future postings, consider a mathSE reviewer focusing on your question as you originally presented it versus how I have edited it.  If you are interested, you can click on the edit button, and pretend to edit your question, to examine the editing that I inserted.

Comment: Also, the `\displaystyle` command may also be used, in questions, answers, or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have\begin{multline}\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}\right)}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}}=\\=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}\left(-3x-3\right)}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}\right)}=\\=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}}\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-3x-3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}}=\\=(-1)\times\frac32=-\frac32.\end{multline}We have$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}}=-\frac12$$because\begin{align}\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}}&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1+\frac1x}{-\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}-\sqrt{1-\frac3x-\frac4{x^2}}}\\&=\frac1{-1-1}\\&=-\frac12.\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand how you got to the fact that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-3x-3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}}=\frac{-3}{2}\\$ could you please explain the way?

Comment: I have corrected and expanded my answer.

Comment: Another question: I found that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}}=1.$$ since $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{{(x+3)}^2}{{x^2+5}}=1.$$ we have that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3}}{\sqrt[6]{x^2+5}} = \sqrt[6]{\frac{{(x+3)}^2}{{x^2+5}}}$$ Did you get to the same thing and said it is -1 since $x\to -\infty$ ?

Comment: The limit cannot possible be $1$, since the numerator is smaller than $0$ when $x<-3$, whereas the denominator is greater than $0$.